# Camera on focus Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I tried to make camera view on focus when i take picture but no lucky i tried with

```
 protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                SetupUserInterface();
                SetupEventHandlers();

                AddView(view);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(@"           ERROR: ", ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

So haw can i do this ? When i take photo it is really bad focus . I want this because use tesseract and need for quality photos.
Sorry for bad English

Comment: We couldn't see the detail of your code,could you please share more code snippets or a basic demo so that we can help you better?

Comment: For using Camera or media you have to use Media Library. This blog describe usage and detailed usage of that https://xamarinhelp.com/use-camera-take-photo-xamarin-forms/